# C++ querying through Soci doesn't work on computer that is not the owner

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, soci

So I have this code:

```
soci::session*              mSql;
mSql = new soci::session("sqlite3", "database.db");
soci::rowset<soci::row> rs = (mSql->prepare << "SELECT * FROM tab");
```

When I run this on the machine that created it, it works perfectly.

However, when I run it on another computer, either physically or via ssh, I get this error: `./executable: symbol lookup error: ./executable: undefined symbol: _ZN4soci7details14statement_impl19exchange_for_rowsetERKNS0_8type_ptrINS0_14into_type_baseEEE`

The error occurs on the third line.

Database permissions are 777.

Why is this occurring and how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure the other computer also has the runtime library.

Comment: @RickAstley sorry, what does that mean?? Like, how would I check?

Comment: A library usually goes with a shared runtime library that contains the actual implementation of the functions, I'm betting that the local machine has that library but the other pc doesn't.